# I got Putty installed need to SSH to my webhost to get MYSQL Error logs

Tags: mysql, ssh, logging, putty

I need the exact commands to type from the beginning in putty to first connect to my db and then to get the error logs contained in /var/lib/mysql/HOSTNAME.err file.
Thanks

Comment: Do you have any familiarity with using the command line at all? Because there's no reason I know of that you'd connect to a database (whose name you never gave) and reading an error log.

Comment: if you dont know how to use basic command line tools or scp/sftp you probably shouldnt be poking around the server

Answer (score 5):

PuTTY isn't the right tool for the job. You want [**psftp**](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/psftp.exe).
run psftp

```
psftp> open remotehost.tld
login as: user
password: your password
Remote working directory is /home/user
psftp> get /var/lib/mysql/HOSTNAME.err
psftp exit
```

or, if as @zypher suggests psftp doesn't work try [**pscp**](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/pscp.exe)

```
pscp user@remotehost.tld:/var/lib/mysql/HOSTNAME.err .
```

Comment: It's more likely that pscp will work than psftp. since scp just runs over ssh port 22 and sftp needs to be configured (which most hosting providers still don't have)